# Pull data from azure keyvault with node

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to pull data from Azure KeyVault with Node. I installed `azure-keyvault` with npm and read some of the guides that Microsoft released (e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-keyvault) but I can't get data to output. Just for testing purposes I'd like to do something like [View contents of Secret in Azure KeyVault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34906096/view-contents-of-secret-in-azure-keyvault) with node.

```
var KeyVault = require('azure-keyvault');
var util = require('util');
var Crypto = require('crypto');
var AuthenticationContext = require('adal-node').AuthenticationContext;

var clientId = 'xxx';
var clientSecret = 'xxx';
var vaultUri = 'xxx';
```

I can't find an API with a list of commands that I can do with the keyvault var, how do I pull data from keyvault?

**Edit**: so I have `var KeyVault = require('azure-keyvault');`

and the KeyVault variable can be used as an object with methods listed in here: http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-node/azure-keyvault/latest/?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the 'azure-keyvault' library docs: http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-node/azure-keyvault/latest/

> I can't find an API with a list of commands that I can do with the keyvault var

you use the "keyvault var" to create a keyvault client. in the link above, see the side menu for a list of all commands.

> how do I pull data from keyvault?

For example, you can use the `KeyVaultClient.getSecrets` function: http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-node/azure-keyvault/latest/KeyVaultClient.html#getSecrets

Comment: Wow the formatting on that was awful, I'm going to edit the original post

Comment: Is that a question? 
That looks right, but then you'll have to authenticate and create the KeyVaultClient. Here is a complete example: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/lib/services/keyVault/sample.js

Comment: I have the clientID and the vaultURI, but I don't know what the clientSecret is

Comment: You need to register your app with AAD, then you get the AppID and secret. see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal

Comment: I read through that document but I can't find anything about the clientSecret. I know the application ID is clientID; is object ID the clientSecret?

Comment: appId is Application ID in the article. clientSecret is Key in the article

Answer (score 1):

The package `azure-keyvault` has been deprecated in favor of the new packages to deal with Keyvault keys, secrets and certificates separately. For your scenario, you can use the new `@azure/keyvault-secrets` package.

The readme at for [@azure/keyvault-secrets](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/keyvault-secrets) has a variety of code snippets you can refer to. You can refer to the [entire sample set for secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure/azure-sdk-for-js/keyvault-secrets-javascript/) too.

Answer (score 0):

To read secrets from azure key vault you can use npm library [read-azure-secrets](https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-azure-secrets), in which you will need to pass client ID, client secret, and vault URI. It will return all secrets from your key vault.
Example -

```
const secretClient = require('read-azure-secrets');

async function loadKeyVaultValues() {

    let applicationID = '';
    let applicationSecret = '';
    let vaultURL = 'https://<your-key-vault-name>.vault.azure.net/';
    let secrets = await secretClient.getSecrets(applicationID, applicationSecret, vaultURL);

    secrets.forEach(secret => {
        console.log(secret);
    });

}

loadKeyVaultValues();
```